# JQTouch question, adding buttons in the footer

Tags: iphone, jqtouch, sencha-touch

I am trying to add 3 buttons in a div which has "info" class as shown 
below( this is basically footer section). Code is shown below

```
<div class='info'> 
    <a class="button" href="#">Full Site</a> 
    <a class="button" href="#">Feedback</a> 
    <a class="button" href="#">Contact Us</a> 
</div>
```

I want to show these 3 buttons at left, center and right. 
(Above code just shows "Contact Us" button on top of the page). How do 
I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no jQTouch/CSS expert, but I believe this is related to the `button` class you're using for each link.

The `button` class absolutely positions items at the top, which is why your buttons aren't appearing in the footer. Additionally all three buttons are being positioned in the exact same spot, but you're only seeing the last/latest one - the Contact Us button.

The CSS file that contains this class is located within each of the theme folders (apple, default or jqt). Each one has a theme.css file.

Again, not being a strong CSS person... my advice would be to create a new class. Keep the attributes you like from the existing button class, but maybe remove the position aspects of it. This will largely depend on what kind of look and feel you want to keep/maintain.

Additionally, it may be easier for you to place your buttons within an unordered list. This gives you some more flexibility when trying to position things through CSS.

```
<div class='info'> 
    <ul class="newULClass">
        <li><a class="newButtonClass" href="#">Full Site</a></li>
        <li><a class="newButtonClass" href="#">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a class="newButtonClass" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```